# How to make a guitar amp switcher?

Tags: amplifier, noise, guitar-pedal

So I'm trying to build a guitar amp switcher (and I don't really know what I'm doing =)).

The idea is that guitar out is connected to **X4** jack and then switched to either **X1**, **X2** or **X3** jack, which goes into amps input.

Then amps speaker out are connected to **X5**, **X6** and **X7** jacks and selected output is routed to **X8** jack.

**S1**, **S2** and **S3** switches are parts of 4 pole 12 way rotary switch.

Currently, I tried a schematic listed below:

[image: Current schematic]
However there is a high pitched noise when using it which disappears when I use some kind of guitar pedal before **guitar in**.

If I connect everything this way I get high pitched noise (everything is connected with TS cables):
[image: Noisy]

And this way there is no noise:
[image: No noise]

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried two X8 options? The ring of the headphone jack tends to be the ground and the tip the signal.  On the X4 setup, you have tied all the signals together and are switching between the grounds.

Comment: @TylerStone Guitars tend to use 1/4 in headphone jacks and the schematic shows headphone jack symbols. I read between the lines.

Comment: @vini_i fixed it, thanks. It is only a misprint in a schematic -- I route jack tips in a real device.

Comment: DC supplies leak a lot of common mode noise on unbalanced cables and the "guitar pedal:" may have a Balun or INA balanced Op Amp in it. Show a block diagram of all the supplies and earth ground.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I've added diagrams

Comment: The Guitar Pedal buffers and lowers the guitar signal impedance and I suspect there is positive feedback at the high pitched frequency from crosstalk. Can you link the DPDT "switch"?

Comment: Or is it just a mechanical box with MUX input buttons and MUX output selector. Is guitar passive pickup or with pre-amp?  This makes a difference on immunity to noise from crosstalk or stray supply noise from output impedance

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 guitar pickups are passive, switcher is a box with a rotary switch.

Comment: OK then I suspect all you need is an Op Amp to buffer the guitar signal to attenuate stray noise from the much lower output impedance.  Either AC coupled single supply or DC coupled bipolar supply. It can also provide voltage gain to improve S/N ratio.  e.g. any preamp

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 maybe there is some way without using active components? What I'm trying to do is to make something like a routable cable.